# Mixing attributes and line item fields in Drupal Commerce Add To Cart form

Tags: theming, forms, commerce

I am currently working on a Drupal Commerce site that offers highly customizable products with multiple attributes.  I am at the stage where i am trying to theme my add to cart form, and am a bit lost.

In my theme, I have created a hook_form_alter, and check for my add to cart form.  The $form variable has 2 groups of form fields:

```
$form['attributes']        // Contains 'Attr_1', and 'Attr_2'.
$form['line_item_fields']  // Contains 'Attr_1_c1', 'Attr_1_c2', 'Attr_2_c1', 'Attr_2_c2'
```

So each attribute has 2 customization options specific to that attribute.  I would like to output my form like so:

```
Attribute 1: (Select Box)
    Customization 1: (input)   // Attr_1_c1
    Customization 2: (input)   // Attr_1_c2

Attribute 2: (Select Box)
    Customization 1: (input)   // Attr_2_c1
    Customization 2: (input)   // Attr_2_c2
```

Thus grouping the proper customization line_item_fields with the proper attributes.  However, since attributes are already grouped in the $form variable, and are separate from the line_item_fields, I am not sure how to do this.  Any thoughts on the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find it easier to organize the form elements in a form template.

e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state{
  $form['#theme'] = array('commerce_add_to_cart_form');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'commerce_add_to_cart_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'form--commerce_add_to_cart',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
    ),
  );
}
```

Then you can use a file in

```
MYTHEME/templates/form--commerce_add_to_cart.tpl.php
```

and in the template file

```
print drupal_render($form['element_name']);
// or
print drupal_render_children($form['element_name']);
```

to specify exactly where to render each form element.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Looks like I have been theming my forms the hard way all this time.  This seems a much more reliable way of doing things (rather than sticking in open and close divs, etc.. in the #prefix and #suffix in hook_form_alter).  This worked great!  I would just add to this that you need to do a "print drupal_render_children($form);" after you output all of your elements for a drupal commerce form, as there are a bunch of hidden fields, etc.. that need to be dumped.